# Number of the beast guitar tone

Tags: guitar, tone

I am trying to get as close to the sound of Iron Maiden on their number of the beast album with what i have, does any one know how to get the type of tone they use. I have a boss katana 50.

Comment: have you got this?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYUPgcnf0-Y

Answer (score 1):

This video is explaining: How to get the "Number of the Beast" GUITAR TONE:

[image]

[image]
[image]